# Silverlight Pivot showing video

Tags: silverlight, pivot, pivotviewer

I have a Silverlight Pivot question I'd really appreciate some help with...

Could someone tell me if it could be possible to show a video via Pivot?
Can you have a link that I might be able to use to call a video in a lightbox?

I love the product but would like to be able to call a video after displaying the image keyframes.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated,

Many thanks

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

No you can't display videos as items in the pivot viewer. Currently, the only acceptable 'visual' is a server-hosted DeepZoom Image.